# php self email form issue

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with my php code. I'm using jquery to validate user input. When I click the submit button I recieve the email, but I cannot return to another page such as "it was successfully sent". I'm new to this and I'm not sure how to get help so I'm going to post the php page where it sends and where I cannot cant that it done so T.T

this page is called ajax.php

---

```
<?
@extract($_POST);
$name = stripslashes($name);
$email = stripslashes($email);
$telephone = stripslashes($telephone);
$message = stripslashes($message);
if(mail("mememe@hotmail.com","Email from $name","
$message

(From $name, $email, $telephone)","From: $email")){
    echo "$name $email $telephone $message";
}
echo "Email Successfully Sent!<br />
<br />
Name: $name<br />Email: $email<br />telephone: $telephone<br />Message: $message";
?>
```

---

this page is the form with jquery validation "onblur" which im submitting from

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0       Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="livevalidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="main">
     <div class="footer_resize">
      <div class="footer">
       <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.html">Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="../services/services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php" class="active">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <div class="body">
    <div class="body_resize">
        <div class="left">
          <h2>Contact for appointment</h2>
          <p><a href="#"></a>
         <strong>Address</strong>
        <br />So Shiq Studio
        <br />380 King Street North
        <br />Waterloo ON
        <br />Tel. 519.721.8060     
        <br /></p>
          <p></p>
          <p><strong>Hours of Operation</strong><br />
            Tuesday: 10AM – 7PM <br />
            Friday: 10AM – 8PM <br />
            Saturday: 9AM – 3PM</p>

            <p></p>
          <p><strong>Private Appointments</strong><br />
            Monday - Wednesday <br />
            Colour Upon Consultation <br />
            *Minimum 2 Services*</p>

          <p><a href="#"></a><br />
        </p>
          <p>
          <a href="#"><strong></strong></a><br />
            </p>
      </div>
        <br /><br /><br />
        <form id="my-form" style="padding-left:16.9em" >

        <table class=shadow border="0" width="71%" style="background:#ececec; font:normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#6b6b6b;" cellspacing="15">
            <tr align="left"><td><strong>Full Name</strong></td><td><input type="text" size="50" id="name" name="name" style="font:normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#6b6b6b;"></td></tr>
            <tr align="left"><td><strong>Email Address</strong></td><td><input type="text" size="50" id="email" name="email" style="font:normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#6b6b6b;"></td></tr>
            <tr align="left"><td><strong>Phone Number</strong></td><td><input type="text" size="50" id="telephone" name="telephone" style="font:normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#6b6b6b;"></td></tr>
            <tr align="left"><td valign="top"><strong>Comments</strong></td><td><textarea id="message" name="message" rows="8" cols="80" style="font:normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#6b6b6b;"></textarea></td></tr>
            <tr align="left"><td>&nbsp;</td><td>
            <input type="button" name:"clear" value="Send" onclick="sendRequest();"  style="font:normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#6b6b6b;font-weight:bold;"/></td></tr>
        </table>

        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var name = new LiveValidation( 'name' );
            name.add( Validate.Presence );

            var email = new LiveValidation( 'email' );
            email.add( Validate.Presence );
            email.add( Validate.Email );

            var telephone = new LiveValidation( 'telephone' );
            telephone.add( Validate.Presence );
            telephone.add( Validate.Telephone );

            var message = new LiveValidation( 'message' );
            message.add( Validate.Presence );

            function sendRequest(){
                if(LiveValidation.massValidate( [ name, email, telephone, message ] )){
                    new Ajax.Request('ajax.php',
                    {
                        method:'post',
                        parameters: $('my-form').serialize(true),
                        onLoading: function(){

                            $('update_div').show();
                            $('update_div').innerHTML = "Sending...";
                        },
                        onSuccess: function(transport){
                            var response = transport.responseText || "No response text";
                            $('update_div').innerHTML = response;


                        },
                        onFailure: function(){ 
                            $('update_div').innerHTML = "Something went wrong...";
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
        <br /><br /><br /><br />
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
  <div class="footer">
     <div class="footer_resize">
      <p class="leftt">
         <a href="https://twitter.com/#!/atmosphair"><img src="../images/rss_1.gif" alt="picture" width="18" height="16" border="0" /></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Atmosphair-Salon/132172773469260"><img src="../images/rss_2.gif" alt="picture" width="18" height="16" border="0" /></a>
      </p><p class="right"> <a href="#">© Copyright COSMO STEFAN All Rights Reserved&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></p>
          <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="clr"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

ive tried what u both below suggested but i cannot get it working T.T. i know the code is messy, im really new to this and just trying to figure out what im doing wrong.. thank u soo much for ur help already.

Answer (score 1):

### **Update**

**Using header()**

To redirect a page using PHP, you use the [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.  This function is designed to send HTTP headers back to the client.  If you send the HTTP Location header with a value, the client will more or less interpret that as meaning "Go to the page specified in the value".

To use the header function to redirect:

```
<?php  
    header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/the/page/you/want/to/go/to.php?success=1'); 
    exit(); 
?>
```

Note that I explicitly say `exit()` after issuing the call to `header()`.  Any code after the header redirect will still be executed *unless you exit*.

**Using $_GET**

`_GET` is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) in PHP.  When PHP loads, it loads all of the variables it finds in the URL into this associative array.  The example above sets a `GET` variable named `success` equal to 1.  You can access the `GET` superglobal like this:

```
echo( $_GET['success'] );
```

You can use this to tell your calling page that your email has been sent by just checking to see if `$_GET['success']` is set and equal to 1, then output your message.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == 1)
        echo( 'Email Successfully Sent!<br />' );
?>
```

There are more complicated ways of doing this, but this I believe is probably the easiest and quickest to implement.  Be sure *not* to output anything before you issue the call to the `header()` function.

Comment: thanks for ur advise. im so new at this that im so confused and struggling. the "GET['success']" part im kinda confused about. say i want to go back redirect back to the email form page.. where would i put this code?

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if you have any further issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have tidy up your code below. It should work

```
<?
@extract($_POST);
$name = stripslashes($name);
$email = stripslashes($email);
$telephone = stripslashes($telephone);
$message = stripslashes($message);
if(mail("mememe@hotmail.com","Email from". $name.$message))
{
echo "Email Successfully Sent!<br /><br />Name:". $name."<br />Email:". $email."<br />telephone:". $telephone."<br />Message:". $message;
}
?>
```

If you want to redirect to success page this is the code

```
<?
@extract($_POST);
$name = stripslashes($name);
$email = stripslashes($email);
$telephone = stripslashes($telephone);
$message = stripslashes($message);
if(mail("mememe@hotmail.com","Email from". $name.$message))
{
//echo "Email Successfully Sent!<br /><br />Name:". $name."<br />Email:". $email."<br />telephone:". $telephone."<br />Message:". $message;
header("location:http://www.yourdomain.com/success.html");
}
?>
```